# Wordpress API return's false when triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const userAction = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://rajivrajput.com/wp-json/mmw/v1/testing', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
        console.log(myJson);
        // do something with myJson
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = myJson;
    }
```

This is my function.php file...

```
$user_id = ""; //<- add this

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
    $GLOBALS['user_id'] = get_current_user_id(); //<- add this

    // route url: domain.com/wp-json/mmw/v1/testing
    register_rest_route( 'mmw/v1', 'testing', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_custom_users_data',
    ));
}
//Customize the callback to your liking
function get_custom_users_data(){
     return $user_info =  get_user_by( 'id', $GLOBALS['user_id'] ); //<- add this
}
```

When I access this https://agriculturecoaching.in/wp-json/mmw/v1/testing though browser it provides a JSON but false when I access through code.. ?

Comment: You do not execute that code in your browser? Or what do you mean by "access through code/browser"? And please provide reference you related to writing that code. E.g. is that supported by the Wordpress API? Do we know?

Comment: When I click your link, all I'm getting is `false`. I suspect the API is only available if you are logged in? You are logged in, thus you see a valid response, but neither me, nor your code has the required access rights.

Comment: how can I get the logged-in user details... I couldn't find the proper way...

Comment: Read the documentation, apply what you've learned. Profit! /E: And: add all clarifications to your question, not in comments beneath. See [help] and [mre] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the api call a X-WP-NONCE header when you are sending the request from the js code, without the nonce wp can't link you to a user in the wordpress ecosystem, pls take a look at the documantation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/